# content type headers from multipart in django

Tags: django, multipart

I have a django endpoint that gets a multipart and I want look at the
content type headers in each part. When I look at
`request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']` I get:

```
'multipart/form-data;
boundary="boundary_.oOo._OTEwMTc3NzM5ODMxMjQxNzkyMTI5OTY3NDQwOQ=="'
```

Googling this I found this [multiparts parser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/multipartparser.py) but I cannot find any docs on how to use it and I can't figure out how to use it.

How can I get the content type headers from each part?